# After splitting settings.py file, mod_wsgi failed to exec Python script file. And application = get_wsgi_application() errors occured over and over

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

Hi everybody I tried to deploy my django project with apache, mod_wsgi in windows.

I splited my settings.py like this:

- source root folder

  - project folder

    - apps
    - config

      - settings

        - **init**.py
        - base.py
        - local.py
        - prod.py
    - **init**.py
    - asgi.py
    - urls.py
    - wsgi.py
  - myenv

After I splited settings.py,
Mod_wsgi failed to exec python scripts file :
'C:/user/users/desktop/source_root_folder/project_folder/wsgi.py'.

Mod_wsgi also show the exception that  Exception occurred processing WSGI script :
'C:/user/users/desktop/source_root_folder/project_folder/wsgi.py'

In Apache24 error log, 'C:/user/users/desktop/source_root_folder/project_folder/wsgi.py'
application = get_wsgi_application()
error occured.

```
# project_folder/wsgi.py

import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
import sys

sys.path.append('C:/Apache24/htdocs/ C:/user/users/desktop/source_root_folder')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project_folder.config.settings'
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project_folder.config.settings')


application = get_wsgi_application()
```

how can i deal with those errors?
please give me some helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to specify the *.py settings file:

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project_folder.config.settings.init'
```